# CSS Stretch content container height if empty overflow if too big

Tags: html, css

What I have is a simple structure of `container` followed by two child elements, `content`and `footer`.

`footer` has a fixed height and `content` should fill remaining empty space. That is easy enough to achieve with `display:table;` but for some reason I can't figure out how to make `content` element overflow to work if its contents exceed website window height?

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xyxj02ge/3/), if you set `content_child` height to say `10px`you can see `content` element filling up the space nicely but when `content_child` is a lot bigger `content` element shouldn't expand the way it does now, what am i missing here?

I would prefer to not use JavaScript to solve this if possible.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container{
  display:table;
  background; black;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.top{
  background: blue;
  display:table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom{
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}

.content{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content_child{
  height: 1000px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="content">
          <div class="content_child"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just by the way; you have an extra closing div. Looks like you're trying to close `<div class="content_child">` twice

Comment: Do you want a fixed footer or what are you trying to achieve? Anyway, there are most likely better ways to achieve what you are trying to do than using tables. So let's not start from the solution but rather the problem.

Comment: @Roope Yes footer should be fixed and content fill in the rest of the space

Comment: And should the content be scrollable in case of overflow, or how?

Comment: @roope content should always fill in the remaining space on the website, if its contents are bigger than the website it should have overflow-y: scroll

Comment: Set height auto no need to defin value

Comment: Should the footer always be visible when the content is bigger, which means that the scroll should appear on the content div?

Comment: Don't use `display:table`, use `display:flex` instead. This should be relatively straight forward then, with the footer being stretch:0 and the content with stretch:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 }

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: #bada55;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.expander {
  height: 1000px;
  /* for demo purposes */
}
footer {
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="expander"></div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to fix body margin to avoid the body scroll...

Comment: It's just to demo the technique...no need to overload the demo..but why not.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you need to do is to change this CSS rule

```
.content{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;   /* change from hidden to auto */
  padding: 5px;
}
```

which will make it look/work like this

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container{
  display:table;
  background; black;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.top{
  background: blue;
  display:table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom{
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}

.content{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content_child{
  height: 1000px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content_child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer... Otherwise I wouldn't have post mine. Anyway I will leave it as an alternative way to solve this

Comment: @vals Do leave it, it is a good and actually better way with `flex` than `display: table` ... :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not seem to be working on firefox for me.

Comment: @Linas Checked that and it is a bug in FF, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565111, so my suggestion is to use `flex` and then create a fallback for those who don't know `flex` using `display: table`. If you can set a fixed height on your bottom div you can of course use `position: fixed`or `position: absolute`, well maybe also `table-layout: fixed` would work.

Answer (score 2):

No need for tables, really. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this may work for you:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And if there's no fancier purpose, you could always just change the `body` background, the same end result here with less code. The only difference is that the scroll bar shows above the footer as well in this one.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Well this seems to work, but it's a dirty hack to do it with position: fixed; I actually need to implement this into a part of my website so it would't really work. I tried to simplify my example as much as i could, sorry for confusing it.

Comment: How would it really not work, i.e. what makes it a dirty hack? Anyway, what is the downside for you on the second simple way?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help if you set height as auto

```
body, html{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container{
  display:table;
  background; black;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: auto;
}
.top{
  background: blue;
  display:table-row;
  height: auto;
}

.bottom{
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}

.content{
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content_child{
  height: auto;
  background: grey;
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate you missed the point of content_child, it's just an example, i don't actually know what height its going to have...

Comment: @linas yes when u set height auto it will manage automatically as per content size

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `calc()` for height of `.top` instead of using `display: table`

```
.top{
    background: blue;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    padding: 5px;
}

.content{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xyxj02ge/4/

Comment: Go for `calc` only if everything else fails. There are likely other simple solutions that will work in all browsers.